# How to modify existing variable in the data frame based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have to modify existing variable in the data frame using conditional formatting.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('upperGI','UpperGI','UpperGI','UpperGI'), 
+                  b = c('C22.0 - Liver cell carcinoma', 'C16.0 - Cardia', 'C15.3 - Upper third of oesophagus', 'C25.9 - Pancreas, unspecified'))
```

I would like to split the variable an into upperGI and HPB when b lies between 22.0 to 25.0.

So the first one and second should be upperGI and third and forth would be HPB.
I am trying to learn dplyr package, that would be great to see in that(if possible).

Comment: I tried using this, but I am getting an error.

```
df2<-mutate(df, df$a = ifelse(df$b>=22.0 & df$b<=25.0, "HPB","upperGI"))

```

Comment: Please do **not** use the comments space for such additional info - edit & update your post instead. Plus, question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @tashu Did you mean for column b to be numbers?  What you have now is quoted numbers, which are actually strings.  We can convert in the answers, or edit it for you, but just trying to understand what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

df_new <- df %>% 
            mutate(num = readr::parse_number(b),
                   col = if_else(between(b, 22, 25), 'upperGI', 'HPB', missing = 'upperGI'))
```

We use `parse_number` to extract numeric from the `b` column and assign `'upperGI'` when `b` is between 22 and 25 and `'HPB'` otherwise.

Comment: Hi Ronak,

Thank you so much for your answer but it is not working for me. As I said variable b is basically a string in my database.

Comment: This is what I have in the other variable:

````
df <- data.frame(a = c('upperGI','UpperGI','UpperGI','UpperGI'), 
+                  b = c('C22.0 - Liver cell carcinoma', 'C16.0 - Cardia', 'C15.3 - Upper third of oesophagus', 'C25.9 - Pancreas, unspecified'))
```

may be i should be more specific in terms of col B.

Comment: @tashu Can you check if my updated answer works for you?

Comment: Thanks again.

I am getting this warning.

Warning message:
In between(b, 22, 25) : NAs introduced by coercion

I believe this is because I have NAs in the col, well other than the range we have given we can include all including blanks in upperGI.

Comment: So if you `NA`'s in `b` this will return `NA` in `col`. What do you want instead of that?

Comment: Better to be replaced by "UpperGI"

Comment: @tashu You can set `missing`  parameter in `if_else` to set it as "UpperGI". See updated answer.

Comment: I am  not getting anything.
I am attaching the output here for you.

NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 15.5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  [12]   NA   NA   NA 15.9   NA   NA 25.9   NA 22.1   NA   NA
  [23]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  [34]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

Comment: @tashu Please add data to your post using which we can reproduce this problem. The code works for the data that you have shared. You can use `dput` to share data. `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to split the variable an into upperGI and HPB when b lies between 22.0 to 25.0.
>
> So the first one and second should be upperGI and third and forth would be HPB.

The latter seems a bit odd given the data set you provide (e.g. the first value is 25 >= 22 >= 22 whilst the second is 26.3 >= 25.0). Like [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64155124/5861244), I assume that you mean that values between 22 and 25 should be `"upperGI"`. In that case, an alternative but similar base R solution to Ronak's is:

```r
transform(df, new_col = c('HPB', 'upperGI')[(b >= 22 & b <= 25) + 1L])
#R>         a    b new_col
#R> 1 upperGI 22.0 upperGI
#R> 2 UpperGI 26.3     HPB
#R> 3 UpperGi 21.0     HPB
#R> 4 UpperGI 25.0 upperGI
```

It adds a `transform` call but saves you three `df$`s.

#### Data

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c('upperGI','UpperGI','UpperGi','UpperGI'), 
                 b = c(22.0, 26.3, 21.0, 25.0))
```

Comment: Hello Benjamin,

thanks much for your reply. I am getting this error below:

Warning message:
In df$b >= "C22.0 - Liver cell carcinoma" &  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 0):

There is also a package called **fmtr** specifically designed for this situation.  You can define a format using the `value()` function, and apply it using the `fapply()` function.  Like this:

```
library(fmtr)

# Set up data
df <- data.frame(a = c('upperGI','UpperGI','UpperGI','UpperGI', 'UpperGI'), 
                 b = c('C22.0 - Liver cell carcinoma', 
                       'C16.0 - Cardia', 
                       'C15.3 - Upper third of oesophagus', 
                       'C25.9 - Pancreas, unspecified',
                       'C23.0 - Livery, pancreas, and biliary surgery'))

df$c <- as.numeric(substr(df$b, 2, 5))

# Define format
fmt <- value(condition(x > 22 && x <= 25, "HPB"),
             condition(TRUE, "upperGI"))

# Apply format
df$a <- fapply(df$b, fmt)
df

#        a                                             b    c
#1 upperGI                  C22.0 - Liver cell carcinoma 22.0
#2 upperGI                                C16.0 - Cardia 16.0
#3 upperGI             C15.3 - Upper third of oesophagus 15.3
#4 upperGI                 C25.9 - Pancreas, unspecified 25.9
#5     HPB C23.0 - Livery, pancreas, and biliary surgery 23.0
```

Comment: Hello David,

I have updated the data frame as you can see above. Will your solution work for my new data frame as well?

Comment: Error in eval(cond[["expression"]]) : object 'X' not found

Comment: @tashu OK. I updated for your new data.  Also make sure your x is lower case. R is case sensitive.